# How can I add a plugin to an existing model?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What should be contained inside the  tags of the .world file. ??
Can I use  tags and inside them use  tags?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12697/how-can-i-add-a-plugin-to-an-existing-model?/) by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All sdf tags are described in detail [here](http://sdformat.org/spec)

To answer your specific question... you can use include tags within a word/sdf file to include model elements, but I don't think it works for plugin elements. The most common usage of include is for models, since people typically include a model file from a world file.

Examples:

[some world files](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/worlds/)

[some model files](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/models/)

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on 2016-02-23**:
I guess, I am not clear with my question.
See http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin#RunningthePlugin
In the .world file, plugin is applied to the box, but in my case I want the plugin to be applied onto a quadrotor (an existing model), how do I do that?

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-02-23**:
you just put the plugin tag in the model tag of the quadrotor model.